# Allow subviews to autoRotate even though parent views are locked in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

I am developing an app in IOS6. I am using storyboard and in my summary I have only portrait mode checked for Supported Interface Orientations. This allows my entire app to be locked into portrait mode without any extra programming.

[image]

In one of my viewControllers I have a subview (UIView) that is hidden and won't appear till a button is clicked. Once the button is clicked and the subview appears, it takes over the screen and displays images in a slideshow.  I would like to make this subview have the ability to autoRotate because some of the images are in landscape.  Is there a way to programatically allow this subview to be able to do this, even though the rest of the app is locked in portrait mode?

Comment: Not with this setting in the summary. And only/best if the slideshow is presented in a modal view.

Comment: I didn't think to use a modal View. I'll keep that in mind. How else would I make the rest of the app locked in portrait mode without this setting then?

Comment: `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` should fit your needs. Remember to subclass `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController` if you use those.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried both and they didn't work. I even tried `(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` and `(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window` but they're not working.    The only code I have been able to get to work is: `-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window` in my AppDelegate file but all that does is lock the entire app in portrait mode all over again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable landscape in a single view controller and disable it elsewhere everything gets a bit complicated.

Essentially you need to set up all your view controllers to only allow portrait via supportedInterfaceOrientations. Then on your single view controller that you want to allow landscape on you can enable it via supportedInterfaceOrientations.

Lastly you then check all the supported orientations for your target.

Its a bit ugly but it works.

Comment: Will this work even if you are using Storyboards for your layout?

Comment: Yes it will work, but you will have to add code to every UIViewController.